# C# How to write to a file in Linux, using absolute path

Tags: c#, linux

I'm writing a C# code to write to a file in Linux, using the absolute path. The path I use in `StreamWriter` is correct but throws `DirectoryNotFoundException`.

```
using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter("/home/myname/results/" + settings.runID + "/CoachAgentDecisions.csv", true))
    {
        streamWriter.WriteLine(totalEpisode);
    }
```

When I try to just write to a relative path it works, but I need to write it to an absolute path.

The path is right but I can't write to it. Is the way I'm using absolute path in Linux or C# wrong?

Comment: *but I can't write to it*: it would be extremely helpful if you describe what happens when you try. Do you get an exception? Which?

Answer (score 2):

You can't write a file to a directory that doesn't exist, you can use `Directory.Create(...)` to create a directory and any sub-directories required.

After it's created, then you can write files to it.

Answer (score 0):

While you write to a file with the absolute path, it will work as similar as you use relative path

Make sure your using the correct folder path, without any unwanted space or symbols, Also confirm whether the folder exists as expected before writing.

```
string filePath = $@"/home/myname/results/{settings.runID}";
if(Directory.Exists(filePath)){
    using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter($"{filePath}/output.txt", true))
        streamWriter.WriteLine("Hello World!");
}
else Console.WriteLine("Folder doesn't exist");
```